# Is there an intermediate representation in PlantUML that can be used for further processing?

Tags: plantuml

I'd like to use the PlantUML syntax to define component structures, which I want to process in an own tool. However, I'd like to avoid having to write a PlantUML parser. Is there some sort of intermediate representation in PlantUML, which I could use for that? It would be perfect to have e.g. a JSON structure which contains all diagram objects and relations among them in a concise way.

I could not find anything in the docs, maybe someone with more insights in the project can help?

Comment: Hello. Maybe you can use this tool: https://github.com/jupe/puml2code to declare component structures in the language of your choice and start from here?

Comment: Thanks Jean-Marc. puml2code allows to use code templates, which I will give a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Jean-Marc Volle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6092788/jean-marc-volle) pointed out, the project [github.com/jupe/puml2code](https://github.com/jupe/puml2code) allows to process puml files and generate source code in different languages using handlebar templates. Currently the code generation is limited to classes in a puml file.

I have used puml2code as a starting point for a new project [github.com/robbito/puml2json](https://github.com/robbito/puml2json), which simplifies the process a bit, as it doesn't require handlebar. Json ist directly generated from the PlantUML code. puml2json currenlty also only supports a subset of PlantUML.